# How to get the return code of a batch started with the PSEXEC command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, psexec

I use the PSEXEC command to start a batch file on a remote computer:

`psexec \\remotemachine -s -d cmd.exe /c c:\test_dir\build_dummy.bat`

The build_dummy.bat script:

```
    @echo off
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    >output_build_bummy.bat.log (
    rem just print something into an output file

    echo.
    echo This is a dummy batch script 

    rem close the file output
    )
    EXIT /B -12345
```

I want that psexec returns the code -12345
However, I get just the process ID of the started cmd.exe.

How can I get the error code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that if I omit the option -d in the psexec call then psexec returns exactly what I need - the exit code of my batch script 
:)

Comment: Even without the -d option PsExec only returns the process ID for me, both in the message produced and the %ERRORLEVEL% value.

Answer (score 1):

Error code of any command is stored in `%errorlevel%` variable. Simply type `echo %errorlevel%`  and you will get it.

Comment: But errorlevel is global, so what if there are other batches or commands running at the same time on this machine. Every other process can write into errorlevel. So I cannot rely on the errorlevel, right?

Comment: Also, when I call echo %errorlevel% I get the process ID (e.g. 8081) of the started cmd.exe and not the error level of the batch (which should be -12345)

Comment: `Psexec` is built to return the PID as `%errorlevel%`. `%errorlevel%` of the batch file would be set on the remote machine (and destroyed, when the batch file ends). PS: there is no such thing as "Global variables" in `cmd`. Every process has its own subset of variables (and so also it's own `%errorlevel%`)